# When I print Word document to pdf the page numbers change to {PAGE }

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, documents

When I print Word document to pdf the page numbers change to {PAGE }.
How do I solve this?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here for us to answer. Please add detail such as what Word version you are using, how are you printing the file, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you've activated the option `print field codes instead of their values`.

[image: screenshot part from word options (advanced)]

I assume this option is checked for you